# How should I organize OpenGL ES 1.x 2D layer tree?

Tags: iphone, opengl, textures, framebuffer, layer

I'm developing a cute puzzle app - [http://gotoandplay.freeblog.hu/categories/compactTangram](http://gotoandplay.freeblog.hu/categories/compactTangram/)/ - , and for performance reasons I decided to render the view with OpenGL. I started to learning it, I'm ok with buffers, vertices, textures in a really basic way.

**The situation:**
In the game user manipulates 7 puzzlePiece, each has 5 sublayers to get some pretty lighting feel. Most of the textures are 256x256. The user manipulates only one piece at a time, so the rest is unchanged during play. A skeleton of app without any graphic here: http://gotoandplay.freeblog.hu/archives/2009/11/11/compactTangram_v10_-_puzzle_completement_test/

**The question:**
How should I organize them? Is it a good idea to "predraw" the actual piece states in separate framebuffers(?)/textures(?) or I can simply redraw every piece/layers (1+7*5=36 sprite) in a timestep? If I use "predraw", then what should I do? Drawing to a puzzePiece framebuffer? Then how can I draw it into the scene framebuffer? Or is there **a simplier way to "merge" textures?**

Hope you can understand my question, if it seems too dim please take a look at my idea on how render an actual piece in my blog (there is a simple flash implemetation of what I'm gonna do) here: http://gotoandplay.freeblog.hu/archives/2010/01/07/compactTangram_072_-_tan_rendering_labs/

Comment: Something glCopyTexSubImage2D? Or glCopyTexImage2D? I just want to merge 5 textures into one with variable subTexture properties, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

A common way of handling textures is to pack all your images into a 'texture atlas' at the start of the game/level.

Your maximum texture size is 1024x1024 and you can have about three of them in memory on the iPhone.

When you have all the images in these 'super textures' you can just draw the relevant area of the large texture.  This has the advantage that you have to bind textures less often and you gain better performance, as well as cutting out any excess space used by the necessity to put small images in power-of-two size textures.